# Grabbing the latest frame from a video stream using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-streaming, video-processing

I am working on a project where I want to process video frames from an IP camera stream using OpenCV in Python. The processing of each frame takes some time (in this case, simulated by a time.sleep(1)), and I want to always process the latest frame from the camera, discarding any frames that were captured while processing the previous frame.

Here is my current code:

```
import cv2
import time

class VideoProcessor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.capture_flag = True
        self.process_frame_width = 640 
        self.process_frame_height = 480  

    def start_model(self, url):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
        while self.capture_flag:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.process_frame_width, self.process_frame_height))
                cv2.imshow('IP Camera stream', frame)
                cv2.waitKey(1)  # Display the frame for 1 ms
                time.sleep(1)  # Simulate 1 second delay for processing
            else:
                print("Failed to read frame, retrying connection...")
                cap.release()
                time.sleep(1)  # delay for 1 second before retrying
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vp = VideoProcessor()
    vp.start_model("http://129.125.136.20/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?camera=1")
```

The issue I'm facing is that, because the processing time for each frame is not negligible, the frames I process are not the most recent frames from the camera. I understand that the OpenCV VideoCapture function buffers frames, and when I call cap.read(), it's providing me the next frame in the buffer, not the latest frame from the camera.

### Attempted solution:

To always grab the latest frame from the camera, I've tried a solution where I create two threads. One thread continuously captures frames from the camera and updates a shared variable with the latest frame. The second thread processes the frame stored in the shared variable.

While this solution works, it's not efficient because the first thread is constantly capturing frames that may never be processed. It wastes resources and can cause unnecessary latency.

### Question:

Is there a more efficient solution, possibly by modifying how cv2.VideoCapture works or using a different method, that allows me to always grab and process the latest frame from the camera, without needing to continuously capture frames in a separate thread?
Note: I've looked into using multithreading to separate the frame capturing and processing, but I would prefer a solution that does not involve multithreading if possible.

### Important note:

I do not care about loosing frame in between, as my main priority is always about grabbing the latest frame.

Comment: Instead of constantly capturing images from the camera, you could either open the camera, read the frame, close the camera then process the frame and repeat (but you would lose fps) or use `cv2.VideoCapture.grab()` and `cv2.VideoCapture.retrieve()` instead of read() [doc on opencv grab](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ae38c2a053d39d6b20c9c649e08ff0146)

Comment: @Tiphel this is a great suggestion! I have tried this, and it nearly worked, but It doesnt seem to work 100% as intended... Il post my attempt in the thread message